# Intercepting the audio from player before it reaches the real sound card

Tags: windows, audio

I am trying to build an application for intercepting the audio from player before it reaches the real sound card and redirect the audio stream to RDP virtual channel so that to play the audio at the speaker of remote client.

How to implement this scenario for windows xp and vista? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The only reliable way of doing this would be to write your own audio device driver, which is not a trivial undertaking.

A compromise solution would be attempt to write an application that records the output to the soundcard. In Vista and above you can do this using WASAPI to do [loopback recording](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In XP, you have to hope that your soundcard manufacturer included a "What U Hear" (sic) record source with their driver. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111603/how-to-capture-pcm-data-from-wave-out) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. My requirement is when the user selects the option 'play at remote system' over RDP the audio which runs through player at terminal server should be played at remote client with low latency. Is there any way redirect the audio directly without recording the output to the sound card?

Comment: @user369287 you'd again be back to writing your own audio device driver. Can't you just turn off the speakers on the local machine?

Comment: Thanks for the  reply.Is it possible to redirect the audio directly from player to RDP virtual channel without using the concept of own audio device driver?

Comment: My answer above states the only two ways I know of doing this. I don't think you have any other option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. How to use that own audio device driver to redirect the audio stream from server to client?

Comment: How to send audio from player to virtual audio device driver and pass it to RDP virtual channel?

Answer (score 3):

If your budget allows it, you could try with [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm#download). It is a commercial virtual audio driver that you could use behind the scenes (as Mark Heath recommended).

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using Stereo Mix in your recorder devices section of your windows. However it captures analog output from your sound card and you should stick this in your mind that it's analog, not digital. And yes I am searching to capture audio stream before reaching sound card just like you, so I hope if somebody knows how to do this, shares answer with us.