# vb.net capture system audio to stream

Tags: vb.net, audio, stream, speech-recognition

Is it possible to capture all/any audio played by a PC into a system.io.stream, so that it can then be run through speech recognition (System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine)?

Essentially I'm looking to pefrom speech recognition on any audio on the client PC, google seems to suggest that capturing a stream like this can be done using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound, however I cannot honestly determine how.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: for what it is worth, there are commercial packages like http://www.applian.com/replay-music/ that capture any audio played by the PC. So there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808287/windows-vista-7-how-to-sample-output-audio-mix/5808780#5808780) for a solution on Vista/Win7, and take a look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196259/intercepting-the-audio-from-player-before-it-reaches-the-real-sound-card/6227855#6227855) for WinXP.

Summary: 
You can use [Loopback recording](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [WASAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Vista/Win7, but there is no equivalent API in WinXP, however a partial solution can be achieved with a virtual soundcard driver.