# Audio enhancement over windows

Tags: audio

I am from signal processing background. When I listen audio from youtube, sometime I feel the chances of improvement in audio quality at run time. These basic improvements will be auto adjusted as per the audio content. I mean, there is a possibility of write a generalized or feedback based algorithm.

I am aware to test my algorithm on offline audio(recorded audio file). But I do not know, how can I interface my algorithm with youtube audio? Is it possible to write some windows API which activates whenever any audio plays over the machine.

Comment: As I understand it, you would have to write a sound driver.  Not a trivial undertaking, to be sure.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196259

Comment: Is this something for your own use, or something you want to be easily installable by everyone?  Loopback audio drivers already exist, and you can use them to pass audio through your application.  I think you can also write DirectShow filters, but I have no experience with them.

Comment: @Brad It shd be installable by everyone.

Comment: @hari In that case, you may have to buy a loopback driver that you can whitelabel.

Comment: @Brad Any open source loopback driver?

Comment: @hari None that I know of.  I think this guy will license one to you though:  http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm