# Listen to WaveOutDevice

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

After choosing a waveout device I want to listen to it every second in order to monitor its volume. How do I go about doing this? I have not found any example regarding listening to a playback device output.

```
int waveOutDevices = WaveOut.DeviceCount;
for (int i = 0; i < waveOutDevices; i++)
{
    WaveOutCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveOut.GetCapabilities(i);
    Console.WriteLine("Device {0}: {1}, {2} channels", i, deviceInfo.ProductName, deviceInfo.Channels);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Normally one would listen to a wave out device by hooking up speakers or headphones.

Comment: @jaket Basically trying to do something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15003/VolumeMeter-Managed-DirectX) but with NAudio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture PCM data from Wave Out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111603/how-to-capture-pcm-data-from-wave-out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something supported by the `WaveOut` APIs. If you are on Vista or above you can use `WasapiLoopbackCapture` to intercept the audio from any render device, and WASAPI also supports signing up for volume notifications which would be ideal for our scenario.

Comment: Excellent! If its not any trouble could you also tell me whether its possible that by intercepting the audio whether I can monitor decibel of that audio per sec?

Comment: sure, you could do a calculation to turn values of the samples into dB