# Record from waveOutGetDevCaps? DirectShow?

Tags: winapi, audio

I listed the `waveInGetDevCaps` and it shows me microphone. I however need to record the speaker audio. Is it possible to record devices listed by `waveOutGetDevCaps`? All examples I find are of wave`In`

I am trying to record audio of system. Not audio of mic.

I have two goals, one is a record the sound then do music recognition on it, and the second goal is to record screen and system audio togather. Does `DirectShow` apis record audio as well?

Edit: So I started the DirectShow thing and am able to list `CLSID_AudioInputDeviceCategory` but I can't find an example out there of how to record system audio, does anyone know of one or can provide one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture PCM data from Wave Out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111603/how-to-capture-pcm-data-from-wave-out)

Comment: It's [loopback recording](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316551). You should have respective HW support, and you might need to [enable Stereo Mix/Loopback Recording device](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8243007/868014) first.

Comment: Thanks @RomanR. I'll check those now! :)

Comment: Quick q on that enabling stero mix, is that only done by user? Its not possible to do so programtically? Is that a security feature of windows?

Comment: I think it's possible to enable it programmatically (`SetupDiXxxx` functions?). Perhaps it's disabled by default because the intention is that it's only used by those to realize what it is about (and it does not mess with read inputs/outputs).

Comment: Thanks @RomanR. ! If its not enabled Ill enable it then disable it when I'm done with it. Awesome

Comment: `SetupDiXxxx` functions are here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553567.aspx#ddk_update_driver_function_dg